# I need a help in rewriting the SQL query written in Union to Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query

```
SELECT
    FD_DESC_CD, 
    FD_NM, 
    FD_CUSIP_CD, 
    NASDAQ_SYM 
FROM 
    DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTC.funddesc b 
WHERE 
    a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 
    AND a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE 
    AND a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' 
    AND FD_STYLE_C <> 11 
    AND a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD IN ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  
    AND (a.FD_DESC_CD NOT IN ('Y3RN','N699')) 

UNION 

SELECT 
    FD_DESC_CD, 
    FD_NM, 
    FD_CUSIP_CD, 
    NASDAQ_SYM 
FROM 
    DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTT.funddesc b 
WHERE
    a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 
    AND a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE 
    AND a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' 
    AND FD_STYLE_C <> 11 
    AND a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD IN ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  
    AND (a.FD_DESC_CD NOT IN ('Y3RN','N699')) 

UNION 

SELECT 
    FD_DESC_CD, 
    FD_NM, 
    FD_CUSIP_CD, 
    NASDAQ_SYM 
FROM 
    DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTI.funddesc b 
WHERE 
    a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 
    AND a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE 
    AND a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' 
    AND FD_STYLE_C <> 11 
    AND a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD IN ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  
    AND (a.FD_DESC_CD NOT IN ('Y3RN','N699'))
```

The results should be in below format ..

```
  FD_DESC_CD    FD_NM              FD_CUSIP_CD  NASDAQ_SYM
    CC07    Blackrock Liquidity     09248U718   EIIPX
    CC12    Invesco American        00141A446   GSTIX
    CC15    J.P. Morgan             4812C2577   EIIGX
```

Comment: Aren't all three selects identical?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes these 3 tables are identical. only Schema is different..

Comment: Are you sure the task isn't eliminating `UNION` but rather replacing the `FROM tab1 a, tab2 b` by proper `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: AND why do you think that you need to replace the UNIONs? I doubt this will improve performance

Comment: You are still missing the source data. Since you are not using the table aliases for the selected columns there's no way we can even guess what they look like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query and join them

```
     with t1 as
        (
         Select FD_DESC_CD, FD_NM, FD_CUSIP_CD, NASDAQ_SYM from DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTC.funddesc b WHERE a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 and a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE and a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' and FD_STYLE_C <> 11 and a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD in ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  and (a.FD_DESC_CD not in ('Y3RN','N699')) 
        ), t2 as
        ( 
          Select FD_DESC_CD, FD_NM, FD_CUSIP_CD, NASDAQ_SYM from DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTT.funddesc b WHERE a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 and a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE and a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' and FD_STYLE_C <> 11 and a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD in ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  and (a.FD_DESC_CD not in ('Y3RN','N699')) 

        ) , 
     t3 as (    
    Select FD_DESC_CD, FD_NM, FD_CUSIP_CD, NASDAQ_SYM from DBSYSTP.FP_FUND_DESC a, DBSYSTI.funddesc b WHERE a.FD_ACTIVE_CD = 1 and a.FD_DESC_CD = b.FD_DESCR_CODE and a.FD_GROUP_CD = 'OF' and FD_STYLE_C <> 11 and a.OUTSIDE_FD_TYPE_CD in ('LIP','NFIA','NFPA')  and (a.FD_DESC_CD not in ('Y3RN','N699'))
        ) 
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.* from t1 join t2 on t1.FD_DESC_CD=t2.FD_DESC_CD
          join t3 on t1.FD_DESC_CD=t3.FD_DESC_CD
```

Comment: but i need the results should be as below ..                                      
             FD_DESC_CD FD_NM FD_       CUSIP_CD NASDAQ_SYM
               CC07       Blackrock Liquidity  09248U718 EIIPX
CC12 Invesco American Franchise R5 00141A446 GSTIX
CC15 J.P. Morgan Us Real Estate R5 4812C2577 EIIGX

Comment: Hi Filburt, i have updated the question with the result set in the way i am expecting.